# warning C4552: '<=' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect (C Programming)

Tags: c

The last line in the following line keeps on generating the " warning C4552: '<=' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect" error, but I don't see any fault in it...

```
void countDays(void) {
int i=0;
if (birth_month == 2 && birth_day <= 28) {
    for ( i <= what_birthday ){
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax for the for loop in the code you posted, did you mean something like this?

```
for (; i <= what birthday; ++i) {...
```

If you didn't care about incrementing i after every iteration, you could use a while loop instead.

```
while (i <= what_birthday) { ...
```

The code shouldn't have compiled at all without the semicolons. You get that warning for things like:

```
for (i <= what birthday; ++i;)
```

Because while it is valid code, it's probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

This code is equivalent:

```
void countDays(void) { 
int i=0; 
if (birth_month == 2 && birth_day <= 28) { 
{
```

you probably meant `while` instead of `for`.